# Editing raw data of a FAT drive

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to edit the raw data of a FAT drive (I think I found a solution for NTFS, but didn't work for FAT. I don't have anything with FAT, just all my devices are using it) with C# (the result should be a drive in a different format - my own format). I was able to read the raw data (was nice seeing the FAT from inside) from it using CreateFile and opening a stream using the IntPtr I got, but couldn't write to it.
I tried several computers, USB flash drives, SD cards, floppy disks - nothing.
If it isn't possible with C#, I can do it with another language and later call the function using DLLImport.
Thanks.

Comment: That's a real long story. In short, I want more space (especially when using floppy disks) and my format was designed for different purpose (so it fits perfectly for my project, though I wouldn't use it on daily basis).

Comment: Raw handling of file system data should be done at kernel-level, I think. But it's dangerous, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit/modify the drive on the sector level it could be no longer be fully compatible.

The standard way is to make a big file to fill al the space and then operate on those sectors.

Since your goal is space FAT is actually not efficient. If you control both ends ( read/write) you can just cange sector 0 so that is is not recogninzed as an existing file system and then you can wirte your own sectors. 
Windows would nag you at insertion that the drive is not formatted.